# @media query not functioning for changing color property of an element

Tags: html, css, media-queries, media

Following media query is functioning for `font-size` property of an element but not working for `color` property of the same element:

.CSS:

```
.text-cyan {
    color: #33CCCC;
}
em {
    color: coral;
    font-size: 0.8em
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    em {
        color: coral;
        font-size: 0.5em
    }
}
```

.CSS screenshot 
[image]

HTML:

```
<em class="text-cyan">Start Date: Thursday, September 20, 2018</em>
```

**font-size** successfully changes from `0.8em` to `0.5em` when window size is less than or equal to `600px` but not changing **color** property of the element from `#33CCCC` to `coral`.

Can anyone please help me fix this.

Thanks

Comment: Add your css to the question, but it looks like a specificity issue.

Comment: class is more specific that tag name

Comment: css in its sequence has been added to the question.